# ValidationPipe() does not work on override @Query in Nestjs/Crud

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to validate the parameters that come in the query of a get request, but for some reason, the validation pipe is unable to identify the elements of the query.

```
import {
  Controller,
  Post,
  Query,
  Body,
  UseInterceptors,
  Param,
  Res,
  Logger,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Crud, CrudController, Override } from '@nestjsx/crud';

import { OpenScheduleDto } from './open-schedule.dto';
@Crud(Schedule)
export class ScheduleController
          implements CrudController<ScheduleService, Schedule> {
          constructor(public service: ScheduleService) {}

          get base(): CrudController<ScheduleService, Schedule> {
            return this;
          }

          @Override()
          async getMany(@Query() query: OpenScheduleDto) { 
             return query; 
         } 
    }
```

**OpenSchedule.dto**

```
import { IsNumber, IsOptional, IsString } from 'class-validator';
export class OpenScheduleDto {

  @IsNumber()
  companyId: number;

  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  professionalId: number;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  scheduleDate: string;
}
```

When I make a get request to http://localhost:3000/schedules?companyId=3&professionalId=1

I get unexpected errors:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": [
        {
            "target": {
                "companyId": "3",
                "professionalId": "1"
            },
            "value": "3",
            "property": "companyId",
            "children": [],
            "constraints": {
                "isNumber": "companyId must be a number"
            }
        },
        {
            "target": {
                "companyId": "3",
                "professionalId": "1"
            },
            "value": "1",
            "property": "professionalId",
            "children": [],
            "constraints": {
                "isNumber": "professionalId must be a number"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because when you use `@Query` parameters, everything is a string. It does not have number or boolean as data types like json. So you have to transform your value to a number first. For that, you can use `class-transformer`'s `@Transform`:

```
import { IsNumber, IsOptional, IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
export class OpenScheduleDto {

  @Transform(id => parseInt(id))
  @IsNumber()
  companyId: number;

  @Transform(id => id ? parseInt(id) : id)
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  professionalId?: number;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  scheduleDate?: string;
}
```

---

Note though, that this is unsafe because e.g. `parseInt('5abc010')` is `5`. So you might want to do additional checks in your transformation function.

Comment: Would it be safer to check if the string is numeric before doing the transformation? I guess the package has a IsNumberString decorator.

Comment: @EliseuMonardosSantos You can for example check `!isNan(id)` and return the untransformed id otherwise. The `@IsNumber` validator will reject the untransformed string.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setting `enableImplicitConversion` as `true` in your `ValidationPipe`.

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
  transform: true,
  transformOptions: {
    enableImplicitConversion: true, // <- This line here
  },
}));
```

This should work locally e.g., in a `Controller` or method as well.